# Counter in File does not increment

Tags: php, ajax

I have a file on the server with a counter in it.
When a link is clicked i send an ajax request to a php file that increments the counter in the file. The problem is, the file is created, but the counter not incremented.

When I execute the ajax file directly the counter is incremented.
Do you see why this effekt occurs?

links:

```
<p><a onclick="incCounter('TL1');" href="index.html">Dies ist Testlink1</a></p>
<p><a onclick="incCounter('TL2');" href="index.html">Dies ist Testlink2</a></p>
```

ajax request:

```
function incCounter(element)
  {    
    xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("GET","incCounter.php?e="+element,true);
    xhr.send();
  }
```

ajax file:

```
  $element = $_GET["e"];
  //$element = "testdatei";
  $filename = "clickcounter\\".$element.".txt";
  $counter = 1;

  if(file_exists($filename))
  {
    //counter holen und inkrementieren
    $file = fopen($filename,"r");
    $counter = fgets($file);
    $counter++;
    fclose($file);
  }

  //datei ggfs. leeren und neuen counter schreiben
  $file = fopen($filename,"w");
  fwrite($file,$counter);
  fclose($file)
```

question edit:
Okay what the ... is this?
I added `alert("test");` to the ajax request to make sure the function is executed everytime i click a link. Now it works. Everytime i click the link the counter is incremented. But now everytime the alert shows up. When I delete this line, it does not work anymore. Does anyone understand that?

Comment: It is because you're clicking a link and you're not preventing the default behaviour (follow the link) with your Javascript. The alert prevents it temporarely allowing the ajax to do its job. You need to add an event handler to your hyperlinks and put `event.preventDefault();` in it.

Comment: For example you add an id to `<a id='link1' ..>..</a>` and then in Javascript you do: `document.getElementById("link1").addEventListener("click", function(event){ event.preventDefault(); });`

Comment: Ah okay. Thank you. I didn't knew that. I am thinking about preventing the default behavior, passing the href attribute of the link over javascript to my ajax file and then forward to that page with header("Location: ..."); But i am really not sure if that would be good practice. Is there a smarter way to achieve that?

Comment: And no, you shouldn't use `Header('Location: ... ');` for this. Ajax "prevents" the visitor from ever going to the actual PHP file. Therefor redirecting with PHP will not work. Instead you just use Javascript to redirect the visiter after you're done with the Ajax request. Still, why do you want to use Ajax if you're going to redirect the visitor straight afterwards anyway? You might as well just make the hyperlink go directly towards the PHP file and redirect the visitor with PHP from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When clicking a hyperlink, the browsers default behaviour is follow that hyperlink to a new page. Your ajax is therefor unable to complete the request. To fix it, you need to prevent the default behaviour. This will do the trick:

```
<p><a class="incCounter" onclick="incCounter('TL1');" href="#">Dies ist Testlink1</a></p>
<p><a class="incCounter" onclick="incCounter('TL2','index.html');" href="#">Dies ist Testlink2</a></p>
```

JS:

```
/* Get the hyperlinks */
var counterLinks = document.getElementsByClassName('incCounter');

/* Add event listener to each hyperlink */
for (var i = 0; i < counterLinks.length; i++) {
    counterLinks[i].addEventListener("click", function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
    });
}

function incCounter(element, url = ''){    
    xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("GET","incCounter.php?e="+element,true);
    xhr.send();

    if(url != ''){
        window.location.href = url;
    }
}
```

As you can see, you can pass a second parameter to your function that will browse to another website or page after the ajax is send. This is optional.

Comment: This was not working directly. When I used window.location.href i had the same effect like before. I had to add this to make it work: `xhr.onreadystatechange = function()
    {
      if(xhr.readyState==4 && xhr.status==200)
      {
        var result = xhr.responseText;
        if(url != '')
        {
          window.location.href = url;
        }
      }
    }` I just return true from my ajax file. Thank you very much for your fast and detailed help!!!

Comment: @Mr.K.O.Rolling A yes of course. Sorry I was planning a weekend away that day and it slipped my mind. Glad you figured it out though :)